# Diacope Confusion

Tags: english, grammar

I'm a little confused by diacope as a rhetorical feature. All examples I can find are short simple sentences "drill baby drill" for example.

I'm trying to work out what the correct term would be to describe the repeated use of the would the word "fine" in this example

*"that's all right you see that's fine if I tell him lies that's fine I haven't told them anything about myself at all that's fine I feel fine about it."*

I should point out that this was taken from a play so the lack of punctuation is deliberate and I've typed it out as it is on the page.

Would this count as diacope in action or is it something else? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: nope, that's not it: "[tmesis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tmesis) (plural tmeses) -- *(prosody)* The insertion of one or more words between the components of a compound word.
Synonyms: [diacope](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diacope), tumbarumba", there's examples too: "abso-fucking-lutely"

Comment: @Mitch don't tell me, I didn't edit wiktionary